# Assistant Entities and Different Speakers

Tags: unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, watson-conversation

It is possible to differentiate among speakers/users with the Watson-Unity-SDK, as it seems to be able to return an array that identifies which words were spoken by which speakers in a multi-person exchange, but I cannot figure out how to execute it, particularly in the case where I am sending different utterances (spoken by different people) to the Assistant service to get a response accordingly.

The code snippets for parsing Assistant's `json` output/response as well as `OnRecognize` and `OnRecognizeSpeaker` and `SpeechRecognitionResult` and `SpeakerLabelsResult` are there, but how do I get Watson to return this from the server when an utterance is recognized and its intent is extracted?

Both `OnRecognize` and `OnRecognizeSpeaker` are used only once in the `Active` property, so they are both called, but only `OnRecognize` does the Speech-to-Text (transcription) and `OnRecognizeSpeaker` is never fired...

```
public bool Active
    {
        get
        {
            return _service.IsListening;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value && !_service.IsListening)
            {
                _service.RecognizeModel = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_recognizeModel) ? "en-US_BroadbandModel" : _recognizeModel);
                _service.DetectSilence = true;
                _service.EnableWordConfidence = true;
                _service.EnableTimestamps = true;
                _service.SilenceThreshold = 0.01f;
                _service.MaxAlternatives = 0;
                _service.EnableInterimResults = true;
                _service.OnError = OnError;
                _service.InactivityTimeout = -1;
                _service.ProfanityFilter = false;
                _service.SmartFormatting = true;
                _service.SpeakerLabels = false;
                _service.WordAlternativesThreshold = null;
                _service.StartListening(OnRecognize, OnRecognizeSpeaker);
            }
            else if (!value && _service.IsListening)
            {
                _service.StopListening();
            }
        }
    }
```

Typically, the output of Assistant (i.e. its result) is something like the following:

```
Response: {"intents":[{"intent":"General_Greetings","confidence":0.9962662220001222}],"entities":[],"input":{"text":"hello eva"},"output":{"generic":[{"response_type":"text","text":"Hey!"}],"text":["Hey!"],"nodes_visited":["node_1_1545671354384"],"log_messages":[]},"context":{"conversation_id":"f922f2f0-0c71-4188-9331-09975f82255a","system":{"initialized":true,"dialog_stack":[{"dialog_node":"root"}],"dialog_turn_counter":1,"dialog_request_counter":1,"_node_output_map":{"node_1_1545671354384":{"0":[0,0,1]}},"branch_exited":true,"branch_exited_reason":"completed"}}}
```

I have set up `intents` and `entities`, and this list is returned by the Assistant service, but I am not sure how to get it to also consider my entities or how to get it to respond accordingly when the STT recognizes different speakers.

I would appreciate some help, particularly how to do this via Unity scripting.

Comment: What you are asking seems to apply to Speech to text (STT), not Watson Assistant.

Comment: @data_henrik It is mainly to do with Assistant actually, since I have set up a dialog with intents and entities, and I am trying to see how I can get the Assistant service to recognize my responses as matching a certain entity, etc... The "different speaker" question is STT which is embedded in my main question, but obviously Assistant relies on STT for the utterance text to be sent to it.

Comment: So you have the text from STT which is annotated with the speaker info. Then you send the text to WA. The result needs to be referenced back to the input info (speaker info). Is that your question?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same question about dealing with the Assistant's messages, so I looked at the `Assistant.OnMessage()` method that returns a string like `“Response: {0}”, customData[“json”].ToString()` plus the `JSON` output that will be something like this:

```
[Assistant.OnMessage()][DEBUG] Response: {“intents”:[{“intent”:”General_Greetings”,”confidence”:1}],”entities”:[],”input”:{“text”:”hello”},”output”:{“text”:[“good evening”],”nodes_visited”: etc...}
```

I personally parse the `JSON` in order to extract the content from `messageResponse.Entities`. In the above example, you can see that that the array is empty, but if you are populating it, then that’s where you need to extract the values from and then in your code you can do what you want.

Regarding the different speaker recognition, in the `Active` property whose code you have included, the `_service.StartListening(OnRecognize, OnRecognizeSpeaker)` line takes care of both, so perhaps put some `Debug.Log` statements inside their code blocks to see if they are called or not.

Comment: Thank you, but my `OnRecognizeSpeaker` does not execute, so (I think) no such information is sent to the Assistant service. Ideally, I would like to know how to do that from within Unity. For instance, `OnRecognize` always handles the speech recognition; after which I send the "final" results to my Assistant, but how do I use `OnRecognizeSpeaker`? Also, when the final results are sent to the Assistant, how do I trigger the entities to fire and improve the responses? For example, when an input is matched with an "intent", the service automatically responds. How do I get the entities to effect?

Answer (score 0):

Please set `SpeakerLabels` to `True`

```
_service.SpeakerLabels = true;
```